# CSS card clip to new image not working in IE

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to create a flip effect when hovering over the image and it flip to a new image.
It's working under everything but IE and i'm not sure why.

CSS

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
    -o-perspective: 1000px;
    -ms-perspective: 1000px;
}
    /* flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: perserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

.flipper img {
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    text-align: center;
}

.inlineWrapper {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="view">
            <a href="http://www.harley-davidson.com/">
                <div class="flip-container">
                    <div class="flipper">
                        <div class="front">
                            <img src="~/Content/Images/Main/NoneButton.png" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                            <img src="~/Content/Images/Main/GTFOButton.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: What version of IE are you targeting?

Comment: Testing under IE 11 right not but would be nice to have it for IE 9+